# How to create an instance of Arbitrary for parametric types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm following haskellbook.com and there is an exercise for QuickCheck, long history short I can't figure out how to implement a instance for arbitrary for my type because it has a parametric type

Here is the code

```hs
module First where

import           Test.QuickCheck

-- I have this type that has a type parameter, it's a Maybe like
data Optional a = Some a | None deriving (Show, Eq)

-- I want to check that this is monoidal, but that is not the problem yet
newtype First' a =
  First' { getFirst' :: Optional a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Here I have an undefined. I simply cant do `instance Arbitrary (First String)`
-- And I cant place a concrete type on the undefined place. How can I implement
-- this type class for First' a?
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (First' a) where
  arbitrary = frequency [ (1, return (First' (Some undefined))) --- how I get rid of this undefined ?????
                        , (1, return (First' None))
                        ]
```

I would like to have something like `Some "foo"` in place of `Some undefined`, but I cant
make a a concrete type, I'm struggling with this for some hours and just cant
come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is use the `Arbitrary` instance for `a`.  I can tell you know you need to do this because you already added `Arbitrary a` as a constraint to the instance, but you need to actually *use* it.  For instance:

```hs
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (First' a) where
  arbitrary = frequency [ (1, First' . Some <$> arbitrary) -- here we have `arbitrary :: Gen a`
                        , (1, return (First' None))
                        ]
```

But really, you should go one step further.  Rather than just making an instance for `First' a`, you can first make an instance for `Optional a` that will make your `First'` instance even easier.  Consider:

```hs
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Optional a) where
  arbitrary = oneof [ Some <$> arbitrary -- here we have `arbitrary :: Gen a`
                    , return None
                    ]

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (First' a) where
  arbitrary = First' <$> arbitrary -- this one is `arbitrary :: Gen (Optional a)`
```

(Note that `oneof` is like `frequency` where all the frequency numbers are the same.)

Comment: Thanks DDub, I end up searching for the solution and finding something similar but your explanation make me understand the code I saw earlier. I didn't even thought about implementing Arbitrary for Optional. Also it make sense that I would use the constraint that I put (Arbitrary in this case) thank you!